# Convert string in DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

```
   DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact("2017_10_16 13:52:03.112","yyyy_MM_dd HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
   Console.WriteLine(x);
   "10/16/2017 1:52:03 PM"
```

It gives output as "10/16/2017 1:52:03 PM"
Here I am missing the milliseconds 112. 
I have looked into many online posts but it does not work for me.

Comment: did you try `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("O"));` ?

Comment: `x` is a `DateTime` object.  If you want a specific string you need to use the [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) method.

Comment: You can specify the format while you are printing Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff tt"));

Answer (score 4):

What you have is correct. Only `Console.WriteLine(x);` does not show you milliseconds by default.

If you ask for this: `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("fff"));` you will see your milliseconds